# Linear algebra minimal sum

Tags: linear-algebra

Among all the unit vectors $u=(x,y,z)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, find the one for which the sum $x + 2y + 3z$ is minimal.

How do I get the minimal? I know the unit vectors of $\mathbb{R}^3$ but do I evaluate one by one to know the minimal or there's another way? Please help. By the way it says that I do not need to use calculus for this one but linear algebra.

Comment: Another way to say this is: Minimize $x+2y+3z$ subject to the constraint $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$

Comment: Related but more detailed explanation of @DeepSea answer can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2265741/16192

Answer (score 3):

Let $\vec{u} = (x,y,z), \vec{v} = (1,2,3)$. Then,
$$
\begin{split}
x+2y+3z 
  &= \vec{u}\cdot \vec{v} \\
  &= \left|\vec{u}\right| \cdot \left|\vec{v}\right|\cdot \cos(\vec{u},\vec{v}) \\
  &= 1\cdot \sqrt{1^2+2^2+3^2}\cos \theta.
\end{split}
$$ The minimality of $x+2y+3z$ corresponds to $\cos \theta = -1$, and this means $\vec{u} = -\dfrac{1}{|\vec{v}|}\vec{v}$, or $\vec{u} = -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{14}}\left(1,2,3\right)$, and the minimum value is $-\sqrt{14}$.