# Minimalizing a Sum in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

The question deals with minimalizing sums.

Among all the unit vectors $\vec{u} = \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, find the one for which the sum $x + 5y + 3z$ is minimal.

When I see this problem, I think of Lagrange multipliers. However, I am looking for a way to solve this problem using Linear Algebra methods. My thoughts were that this problem may be some type of projection, but I am not sure that I am understanding what minimalizing the sum actually is. There is a problem similar to this one here: [Linear algebra minimal sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1212442/linear-algebra-minimal-sum), but I don't think I am understanding the reasoning that is used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following the answer you quoted, note that if $(x,y,z) = \vec{u}$ is a unit vector, then $\left\|\vec{u} \right\| = 1$, or, in other words, $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$.

Now, if $\vec{v} = (1,5,3)$ then $\left\|\vec{v} \right\| = \sqrt{35}$. Notice that
$$
x+5y+3z
 = \vec{u} \cdot \vec{v}
 = \left\|\vec{u} \right\| \cdot
   \left\|\vec{v} \right\| \cdot \cos \theta,
$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$.

Thus, minimizing the value of the sum on the LHS is equivalent to minimizing the value of the product on the RHS. But the only thing varying over the product is $\theta$. Hence, the minimum occurs when $\cos \theta = -1$, which happens when $\theta = 180^\circ$, i.e. $\vec{v}$ is in the opposite direction from $\vec{u}$. Thus, $\vec{v}$ must be the rescale of $\vec{u}$ to the unit size, i.e.
$$
\frac{-\vec{v}}{\left\|\vec{v} \right\|} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{35}}(-1,-5,-3).
$$